# Upside php value (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to sort post on archive by custom field, so this is my code:

```html
$the_key = 'date';  // The meta key to sort on
$args = array(
   'meta_key' => $the_key,
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'order' => 'ASC',
);
global $wp_query;
query_posts(
 array_merge(
  $wp_query->query,
  $args
 )
);
```

I have custom field called "date" and the posts sort by his value.
the problem is that: its sort by day, month, year. example of this (wrong) sort:

```
01/05/2015
16/04/2015
28/05/2015
```

that because 01 is low than 16...

So what I need to do? take it upside..
for example if the date value is: 01/05/2015 it become to be 2015/05/01
how can I do that? something like this:

```html
$the_key = 'date';  // value is 01/05/2015
$upsidedate = CODE;  // value is 2015/05/01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split the date using the `explode` method, and the reformat the string:

```
//       M   D  Y
//date = 01/02/2015
$split = explode("/", $date); 
$newDate = $split[2]."/".$split[1]."/".$split[0];
```